# firebase web push image, badge, action and vibration are not working

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, service-worker, web-push

I was trying to implement Firebase Web Push Notifications on my website.
I tried sending a sample web push from Postman with below values:

url: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

header:

```
Content-Type : "application/json";
  Authorization: key=<myKey>
```

method: `POST`

request body:

```
{
 "to" : "cw3K5GEx01c:APA91bG2DA-ljONHngS47SxVAjY9ueLaV2sT9ssWBALha3ycZJo0scpSm9yJDxQE_WVWCr0BepMVyyrg-s_ggxI7izsoUR5sIy_1NMT72N_636U3m2yJnmACNMTLL7zUZ5BrkmyHV3v2",
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "great match!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
 "icon": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fcm-on-web.appspot.com/o/icons8-notification-96(1).png?alt=media",
 "click_action": "https://fcm-on-web.firebaseapp.com",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high"
 },
        "badge": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fcm-on-web.appspot.com/o/icons8-notification-24.png?alt=media",
        "actions": [
          {
            "action": "yes",
            "title": "Yes",
            "icon": "images/yes.png"
          },
          {
            "action": "no",
            "title": "No",
            "icon": "images/no.png"
          }
        ],
        "tag": "something",
        "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fcm-on-web.appspot.com/o/_%2B91 90726 44297_ 20180910_134125.jpg?alt=media",
 "data" : {
 "body" : "great match!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high"
 } 
}
```

And the firebase-messaging-sw.js file content looks like this:

```
 // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('/__/firebase/5.5.6/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/5.5.6/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

  // Customize notification here
    var notificationTitle = 'Message Title, hardcoded inside service-worker';
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      {
        badge: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fcm-on-web.appspot.com/o/icons8-notification-24.png?alt=media",
        actions: [
          {
            "action": "yes",
            "title": "Yes",
            "icon": "images/yes.png"
          },
          {
            "action": "no",
            "title": "No",
            "icon": "images/no.png"
          }
        ],
        tag: "something",
        image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fcm-on-web.appspot.com/o/_%2B91 90726 44297_ 20180910_134125.jpg?alt=media"
      });
  });
```

some google docs says that I don't have to specify the notification title, body and icon in service worker if it is explicitly shown in the postman request body.
Just like that doc, Notification title, body and icon are present right where it should be. But even when I gave valid values for image, badge, action and vibration fields in both postman request body and service worker, those four web push features are not working for my case. I'm using both firebase hosting, cloud functions and cloud messaging for my project.
Here's the cloud functions index.js file content:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();
const firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp(
    functions.config().firebase
)


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/sendPush/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    Push List
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>List Of Recent Push Messages</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    `);
});
app.post('/sendPush', (req, res) => {

    firebaseApp
        .messaging()
        .send({
            "token" : "e29EjTpwmmY:APA91bHRGY8ihyBl9tnYVIP4RCVLbLpg4zwFEmHvdxhcfy5c7AM3EkbAl29nLSc009oIA4ZiTm9dLqMsz3-rXtn2IEA7_epHSwRxldykNW9Aw_ClncYUSQW7BHB3m2HjSfSBdy02BfXa",
            "notification" : {
                "body" : "great match!",
                "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
                "icon": "https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/minecraft-creeper.png",
                "click_action": "http://localhost:5000",
                "content_available" : "true",
                "priority" : "high"
                },
            "data" : {
            "body" : "great match!",
            "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
            "content_available" : "true",
            "priority" : "high"
            } 
           })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err)
        });



});
app.put('/sendPush/:id', (req, res) => res.send(req.body));
app.delete('/sendPush/:id', (req, res) => res.send(req.params.id));
app.get('/sendPush/', (req, res) => res.send(req.params));
```

**edit:**
If  I put below code into the service worker and change postman body into second below code, the notification works with a  title, body and actions, hardcoded inside the service-worker.
firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts('/__/firebase/5.5.6/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/5.5.6/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png',
    actions: [
      {
        "action": "yes",
       "title": "Yes",
       "icon": "images/yes.png"
     },
     {
       "action": "no",
       "title": "No",
       "icon": "images/no.png"
     }
       ]
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

and postman body:

```
{
 "to" : "exK2dzY0-HY:APA91bFroNju11PkRhFZb56ZkX7nj0QeQfWAhu_xTmNGxmiUZXZPpyomXz1DHohDo3MJgJS6dI6Bayk2mpQJVgdihVBPYYQGI0D6Xcxr1GFmXBgeMQ3W46rczQw40XBtHypeiTymKb_g",
 "notification" : {
 },
 "data" : {
 "body" : "great match!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
    "custom_data": "Hey yo !"
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround you could try here. It's about send the notification data via the data object and read it from client and create then the notification.

https://github.com/gauntface/web-push-book/issues/40#issuecomment-280054109